# What would be the best place to buy a Macau Pass Anonymous Card while traveling from Hongkong Airport to Macau via Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge?

Tags: hong-kong, macau

I am traveling to Macao via Hong Kong in the next few days. I plan to go from Hong Kong Airport to Macau via Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge. In this journey, where would be the best to buy a [Macau Pass Anonymous Card](https://www.macaupass.com/product/4)?

Macau Pass website mentions the following places to buy the pass:

```
7-Eleven convenience stores
Circle-K convenience stores
Sunsco Supermarket
US MART
Macau Pass World Trade Centre Customer Service Center
Macau Pass Northern Customer Service Center
Macau Pass Taipa Customer Service Center
```

However, none of these appear to be near Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge.

Comment: Are you taking the HKIA-Macao direct bus?  If so, you don't need (and AFAIK cannot use) the Macau Pass: https://www.macauhkairportbus.com/

Comment: Are there none on the way from the airport to your accommodations, bus station or other place you'll be passing along they way? Having never been to Hong Kong, I wouldn't know for certain, but in the US anything labeled "convenience store" appears about every 3-4 blocks...

Comment: @lambshaanxy, I am taking the shuttle bus via Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge (https://www.hzmb.gov.hk/en/cross-boundary.html). macauhkairportbus.com timings are not suitable for me.

Comment: @FreeMan, As far as I see on Google Maps, there are not any on or near my route.

Comment: You might just have to go out of your way a bit... :shrug:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macau pass is not (officially) available in Hong Kong - I cannot find any posts from local forums saying it is sold in any outlets in Hong Kong (not even the Hong Kong - Macau Ferry Port in Sheung Wan). This means the OP can only purchase a Macau Pass once they reach Macau (i.e., *after* taking the Hong Kong - Zhuhai - Macau Bridge shuttle bus).

This is unlikely an issue to the OP as Macau Pass is not accepted for payment at the HZMB Hong Kong Port anyway, [according to the operator (Chinese only)](https://www.hzmbus.com/passenger_service.html?id=71). It is accepted at the Macau Port for the shuttle buses travelling the other way, though. The OP may consider paying for the shuttle bus ticket using, e.g., HKD/MOP/RMB cash, (Hong Kong) Octopus, Visa/Mastercard (debit or credit), WeChat Pay, or AliPay.

Given the OP's route, the earliest point where one can buy a Macau Pass is a convenience store at the arrival level in the HZMB Macau Port (G/F, Unit C115 from [this document](https://www.macaupass.com/uploads/20201130/MSF%E5%95%86%E6%88%B6%E5%8C%AF%E7%B8%BD_202011.pdf) hosted by Macau Pass (entry 2315)). The store and the surrounding area looks like [this](https://youtu.be/_nfo-noVMiQ?t=812) or [this](https://youtu.be/qwop0Kp0tsc?t=1160) in July 2023. It does mark up the price (MOP 140 cash / MOP 145 card payment for a card with, officially, MOP 100 balance and MOP 30 card fee). I am not affiliated with the store or the youtube channels.

The OP may also consider getting a Macau Pass from any of the outlets listed on the Macau Pass website, with the official price of MOP 130, once they reach the urban area in Macau. It is the "best" in terms of price, though it comes with the inconvenience of sourcing MOP cash for the bus or taxi ride into town.

---

Aside: There are [many local buses that go between Hong Kong International Airport and HZMB Hong Kong Port](https://hongkongbuses.fandom.com/wiki/Hong_Kong-Zhuhai-Macao_Bridge). Most of them are Airport buses that are bound for Hong Kong city centre and are priced accordingly. The most economical option would be [Bus B4, operated by New Lantao Bus](https://nlb.com.hk/route/detail/87) (HKD 9.1).

Comment: Thanks. Would I be able to use my master card to purchase tickets on board the local buses in Hongkong and Macau?

Comment: Mastercard is supported in most local buses in Hong Kong (via contactless on the bus). Ironically [it is not accepted on Bus B4](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E6%96%B0%E5%A4%A7%E5%B6%BC%E5%B1%B1%E5%B7%B4%E5%A3%ABB4%E7%B7%9A) (or any other New Lantao buses - they only take HKD cash, Octopus, and AliPay). The airport bus routes A31, A33X, or A36, which stop at the HZMB Hong Kong Port, take Mastercard contactless and cost less than HKD 20 if you prefer to avoid withdrawing/holding HKD.

Comment: Thanks. I only have Mastercards and a maestro card. What would be the best way for me to make payments in Macau?

Comment: @Komkom Sorry, I mistyped - not supported _on Macau buses_. Accepted in many shops in Macau. For smaller shops / street trader it is likely to be MOP/HKD   cash only.

Comment: (Updated) Mastercard is not supported on Macau buses. It is [the subject of a recent written question](https://www.al.gov.mo/uploads/attachment/2023-08/2749364d48d38b4f7c.pdf) from a Legislative Council member to the Macau government. As of today the government has not gotten back yet.

Comment: Thanks. Your initial comment had left me worried there for a while :-) I guess I will just take a cab from HZMB Macau port to my hotel. Hopefully the cabs will accept MasterCard right?

Comment: Unfortunately this is beyond my knowledge. My research indicates it is patchy at best so I would not count on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147976/discussion-between-kom-kom-and-b-liu).

Comment: "Given the OP's route, the earliest point where one can buy a Macau Pass is a convenience store at the arrival level in the HZMB Macau Port (G/F, Unit C115 from this document hosted by Macau Pass (entry 2315)). The store and the surrounding area looks like this or this in July 2023. It does mark up the price (MOP 140 for a card with, officially, MOP 100 balance and MOP 30 card fee). " This is correct. I was indeed able to buy the Macau pass here. Note that they also accept MasterCard for payment albeit then they charge MOP 145.

Comment: @Komkom I've added the MOP 145 for card payment info in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/c5RjPUy1Kg3XAhsS8), it appears to me that there is a Circle K convenience store located near one end of the HK-Z-M bridge, just East of the Honk Kong Chep Lap Kok airport:

[image]

Not only that, but it appears to be in a building that is conveniently located near the parking lot for those driving to the airport via said bridge. To be fair, this does look to be a bit of a hike from the airport terminal itself, but you might find that there's a shuttle that can take you there, or that even the bus terminal itself may be located on this little piece of artificial island.

Comment: (-1) It is not possible to get a Macau Pass from a Hong Kong Circle-K (at least, not officially). Also, there are multiple bus routes that depart from Hong Kong International Airport and stops by the HK-Zhuhai-Macau Port. These make the answer rather unhelpful.

Comment: Based on the OPs requirements, it seemed like this was useful, especially since he couldn't find a Circle K near the bus. I will bow to your knowledge, @B.Liu, and hope that you will post a rather _more_ helpful answer.